# Logstash fails to stream data to ES - Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I have encountered a very frustrating error and I don't manage to resolve it.

I am trying to stream data with Logstash from SQL Server to ES, but I am getting the following error:

> Attempted to send a bulk request to elasticsearch' but Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down! {:error_message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable:
> Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down

Notes:

1. I have noticed that the error, usually, occurs not immediately but after some time (can be even hours), which in it the streaming works.
2. The cluster's structure consists of 3 ES servers.
3. Seemingly, the error mentioned above occurs randomly in one of the 3 servers of the cluster.

Could anyone please help me in this matter?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, is your SQL server an AWS EC2 instance installed with SQL? What is the OS of the SQL server? Did you check the Security group(s) of ElasticSearch Service (and EC2 if the SQL is hosted in one) and if the IPs are allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Since it did not occur immediately, just about a time, try to find file (assumption you use Linux)

`/etc/sysctl.conf`

change value of options like this (you may be need other number)

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Reference document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html

Comment: First of all, thanks! Do you mean the sysctl.conf file in the Logstash server or in the ES servers?
The file contains the following:
# sysctl settings are defined through files in
# /usr/lib/sysctl.d/, /run/sysctl.d/, and /etc/sysctl.d/.
#
# Vendors settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/.
# To override a whole file, create a new file with the same in
# /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there. To override
# only specific settings, add a file with a lexically later
# name in /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there.
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).